# Fixed Navbar is Leaving Div and Overflow, Width Specifications, and Tag Specifications don't work

Tags: html, css, optimization

I am working on a website and I'm currently optimizing for portrait mode devices. I want to have a fixed navbar on the top of the page so that no matter where you are, you can click one of the navigation buttons. But for some reason, the navbar keeps leaving the div that it is in. I can't figure out where in my code I'm messing up or what I might be missing. I've tried limiting the width percentage, using overflow:hidden, and even specifying things in the li. The navbar doesn't leave the div if I leave the position at default (static) or use position: sticky.

```css
/* Phone Styles */

body {
  color: #7a503c;
  background-color: #bd7d3b;
  background-image: url("https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/34a8808d-f7f3-40c0-bfb4-e0928a5dabde/d3991v1-c838c361-483b-4d3e-8ee7-94f135191afc.jpg/v1/fill/w_900,h_900,q_75,strp/seamless_wood_planks_texture_by_10ravens_d3991v1-fullview.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3siaGVpZ2h0IjoiPD05MDAiLCJwYXRoIjoiXC9mXC8zNGE4ODA4ZC1mN2YzLTQwYzAtYmZiNC1lMDkyOGE1ZGFiZGVcL2QzOTkxdjEtYzgzOGMzNjEtNDgzYi00ZDNlLThlZTctOTRmMTM1MTkxYWZjLmpwZyIsIndpZHRoIjoiPD05MDAifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6aW1hZ2Uub3BlcmF0aW9ucyJdfQ.FNq13s8fPuiMiCTzg2YdIKZqYHU_E3LYzIL6LTVXX6s");
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Hind Siliguri', sans-serif;
}


/* MAIN BODY */

div {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'Berkshire Swash', 'Galada', 'Merienda One', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7a503c;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 300%;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}

section h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

section a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #7a503c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #7a503c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.sectionlinks a:link,
div.sectionlinks a:visited {
  color: #7a503c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.sectionlinks a:hover,
div.sectionlinks a:active {
  color: #7a503c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.sectionlinks {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}


/*NAVIGATION*/

#navbar {
  background-color: #af0000;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'Merriweather', 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 -1.25em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#navbar ul {}

#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.0625em 0.3125em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dca56;
}

#navbar a:link {
  color: #dca56d;
}

#navbar a:visited {
  color: #dca56d;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: #dca56d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar a:active {
  color: #dca56d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1Spx solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cooking Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="help.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Berkshire+Swash&family=Galada&family=Merienda+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri&family=PT+Mono&family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&family=Merriweather:wght@300&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Cooking Website</h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpages/appetizers.html">Appetizers</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpages/maindishes.html">Main Dishes</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpages/sides.html">Sides</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpages/desserts.html">Desserts</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpages/snacks.html">Snacks</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpages/drinks.html">Drinks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>

      <img src="https://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-davys-grey-solid-color-background.jpg" alt="cooking image">


      <div class="sectionlinks">

        <h4><a href="subpages/quickmix.html">Quick Mix</a></h4>
        <h4><a href="subpages/extras/measurementconversion.html">Measurement Conversions</a></h4>
        <h4><a href="subpages/ingredients.html">Ingredients</a></h4>

      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your nav to be expanded for full width you can try:

```
#navbar {
background-color: #af0000;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'Merriweather', 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
top: 0;
position: sticky;
width: calc(100% + 2.5em);
left: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: -1.25em -1.25em 1.25em -1.25em;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

In case you need full width nav bar on top

```
#navbar {
background-color: #af0000;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'Merriweather', 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. They both worked out and looked nice on the website. But I noticed that on the first result, the navbar appeared underneath the header h1 even though top is set to 0. Is there a way around that? Either way, thank you so much.

Comment: @BigSad2020 position sticky means that block will have his place by creation order in html and will stick to top:0 during scroll. So just swap navbar with header in your html or define H1 after navbar

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you.